# How can I generate dialogs dynamically using the Microsoft Bot Builder SDK for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I am building a tool that allows users to generate their own custom form surveys. I would like to give them the ability to convert these traditional form surveys into a chat conversation. I am already using the [Microsoft Bot Builder SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/) to interact with users through chat.

How can I generate dialogs dynamically using the form structure that is stored in my database? Assume that I have an array like this one stored in my database:

```
var form = [
    {
        inputType: 'text',
        prompt: 'What is your first name?'
    },
    {
        inputType: 'choice',
        prompt: 'Select your gender',
        values: ['female', 'male']
    }
];
```

How can I generate a waterfall dialog using this array? I know I can just manually write the dialog code using prompts etc. if I know what the survey questions are all the time but I have to generate the dialog based on a dynamic form that users save. I can't find any information about how to achieve this. Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a community contributed tool called "Form Flow" - it is designed to accomplish a similar idea to yours.

You can find the NPM package here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-formflow

More details available on the GitHub project repository here:

- https://github.com/gudwin/botbuilder-formflow

**Overview:**

> This Library will allow your bot to request complex forms from a user. It helps to build a waterfall dialog that will handle the whole form flow. The library will split into a list of dialogs required for each field. You can use predefined prompts or create you custom dialog wrappers around MBF prompts. Dialogs for each field evaluated separately and could be customized. The Library features:
>
> - Standard Prompts plus prompts for emails and urls;
> - Validators, Prompts, Error Prompts and Value extractors could be customized by a developer
> - Subdialogs are supported

**Example:** [Simple registration form](https://github.com/gudwin/botbuilder-formflow/blob/master/examples/signup.js):

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
const formFlow = require('../../botbuilder-formflow');

let signupForm = [
  {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "login",
    "prompt": "Please enter your login",
    "response": "Your login is %s"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "password",
    "prompt": "Please enter your password",
    "response": "Your password is %s"
  }
];


let connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
let bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.dialog('/', [
  session => session.beginDialog('/form'),
  (session, response) => session.endDialog(`Form result: ${JSON.stringify(response.response)}`)
]);
formFlow.create(bot, '/form', signupForm);

console.log('To start registration flow press [[ENTER]]');
```

Comment: This solution seems to work great if the signupForm array is defined when the script loads. If I initiate the script with `var signupForm = []` and dynamically assign its value in the dialog, it doesn't work. It seems like once `formFlow.create()` is initiated, I can't change the values of signupForm. I need to do this as I am fetching the array from the database when the dialog starts (based on the message of the dialog). Any thoughts on how I can dynamically set the value of signupForm?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, besides leveraging the npm package as @nilsw mentioned, you can try to build up an Adaptive Card json string by yourself from the entities in your database.

The field definition code snippet is simple:

```
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Your name",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "myName",
      "placeholder": "Last, First"
    },
```

You can refer http://adaptivecards.io/samples/InputForm.html for the input form sample.

And also, refer to http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Choice.html for the fields definitions.